# Connect 2 numbers through call api twilio

Tags: api, communication

I need a Twilio API which when hit should first call the customer support agent (person1) and when he picks up the call it should redirect the call to the customer (person2).

Current situation: When a customer support agent calls a customer, the customer support agent has access to the customer's number which is obviously not good for privacy.

So by using the Twilio API the customer agent won't have direct access to customer's number. I want to know if it is possible with Twilio.

Comment: *how to implement this* is off-topic for this site, you can only ask for software packages - please read the help and [edit] your question. Why the *python* tag?

Comment: I am having python at my backend (Django).